# Construct a formatted list of strings in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have several lists consisting of strings like this (imagine them as a tree of sort):

$list1:

```
data-pool
data-pool.house 1
data-pool.house 1.door2
data-pool.house 1.door3
data-pool.house2
data-pool.house2.door 1
```

To make them more easier to parse as a tree how can indent them based on how many `.` characters occur while ditching the repetitive text earlier in the line? For example:

```
data-pool
  house 1
    door2
    door3
  house2
    door 1
```

The way I approached it counting the occurrences of `.`s with `.split('.').Length-1` to determine the amount of needed indents and then adding the spaces using `.IndexOf('.')` and `.Substring(0, <position>)` feels overly complicated - or then I just can't wrap my head around how to do it in a less complicated way.

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me?

Comment: Is the number of child nodes always between 1 and 2?

Comment: @ITM: It could be, but going through hundreds - thousands of lines seems heavy.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: No, the text can vary a lot and be almost anything.

Comment: What I meant on my previous comment was, is it possible to have something like this: `data-pool.house 1.door1.something.something.something.`? Or will there always be 1 door and 1 house?

Comment: Yes, there can be several "nodes" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work as long as the number of nodes from line to line are ordered, what I mean by this is that it will not look "pretty" if for example the current node has `n` elements and the next node has `n+2` or more.

To put it into perspective, using this list as an example:

```
$list = @'
data-pool
data-pool.house 1
data-pool.house 1.door2
data-pool.house 1.door3
data-pool.house 1.door4.something1
data-pool.house2
data-pool.house2.door 1
data-pool.house2.door 2.something1
data-pool.house2.door 3.something1.something2
data-pool.house3
data-pool.house3.door 1
data-pool.house3.door 2
'@ -split '\r?\n'
```

The function `indent` will take each line of your list and will split it using `.` as delimiter, if the count of elements after splitting is lower than or equal to `1` it will not perform any modification and display that line **as is**, else, it will multiply the `$IndentType` containing **2 white spaces** by the number of elements of the split array **minus 1** and concatenate it with the **last element** of the split array.

```
function indent {
param(
    [string]$Value,
    [string]$IndentType = '  '
)
    $out = $Value -split '\.'
    $level = $out.Count - 1

    '{0}{1}' -f ($null,($IndentType*$level))[[int]($out.Count -gt 1)], $out[-1]
}

$list.ForEach({ indent $_ })
```

**Sample:**

```
data-pool
  house 1
    door2
    door3
      something1
  house2
    door 1
      something1
        something2
  house3
    door 1
    door 2
```

Comment: This works as expected, thank you! The lines are sorted & ordered before this function takes place so the nodes and elements are properly kept in place.

Comment: @lapingultah thats good to know, and happy to help.

Comment: @lapingultah not sure i'm following, could you ask a new question explaining in detail this new requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

the approach to get the last element of the string is below

```
## String
$string = "data-pool.house 1"
## split the string into an array every "."
$split = $string.split(".")
## return the last element of the array
write-host $split[-1] -ForegroundColor Green
```

Then to test against each string

```
$myArray = ("data-pool", "data-pool.house 1", "data-pool.house 1.door2", "data-pool.house 1.door3", "data-pool.house2", "data-pool.house2.door 1")
ForEach($Name in $myArray) {
    ## String
    $Name = $Name.ToString()
    $string = $Name
    $split = $string.split(".")
    ## return the last element of the array
    write-host $split[-1] -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: I don't understend the logic in this. `$myArray` here is already cast as String so `.ToString()` is not needed and `$string = $Name` could be omitted using only `$split = $Name.split(".")` instead. Also this doesn't count the needed indents.

Comment: Since I do not have exchange to build the array. I used what you provided to demonstrate, what you need to do.